# Having trouble with Newton's Method. The equation x - rx^-1...

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

The equation $x - Rx^{-1} = 0$ has $x \pm \sqrt{R}$ for its solution. Establish the Newton's iterative scheme, in simplified form, for this situation (to compute the root). There is no need to carry out the actual computation

So far I have

$x - \frac{R}{x}$

so $f'(x) = 1 + \frac{R}{x^2}$ But now what do I do? I'm a little confused.

Here is what I have:

$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \implies x_n - \frac{x_n - \frac{R}{x_n}}{1 + \frac{R}{x^2_n}} \implies x_n - [ \frac{x^2_n - R}{x_n} * \frac{x^2_n}{x^2_n + R}]$

which $\implies x_n - [ x^2_n - R * \frac{x_n}{x^2_n + R} ]$

so... now I'm getting $\frac{x^3_n + x_n R - x^3_n + x_n R}{x^2_n + R}$

Finally I am getting: $\frac{2x_n R}{x^2_n + R}$

Comment: Yea but what do I do after? Is that it?

Comment: The recurrence is standard, $x_{n+1}=x_n -\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$. Plug in the known expressions for $f(x_n)$ and $f'(x_n)$, and simplify.

Comment: Am I approaching this correctly? Check out my updated work in the post above @AndréNicolas

Comment: You have an error in your last expression .Your approach is correct. You must also in this particular problem, ensure that each $x_n$ is not zero so that $x_{n+1}$ exists,( or apply the general theorem that will ensure it.)

Comment: How would I ensure that each $x_n \ne 0$ Would I multiply each $x_n$ by $x_n$? What is the "general theorem" I should apply?

Comment: There is a mysterious $2$ that suddenly appeared. And you are a long way from full simplification. After you correct the $2$, and do some cancellation, you are probably expected to bring the $x_n$ in front into the story, by expressing the whole thing as a fraction involving the common denominator $x_n^2+R$.

Comment: Ahh, dk how that got there. So I should factor a $x_n$ I bet... Trying that now

Comment: OK, and don't worry about $x_n=0$. If we start with $x_0=0$, the computation goes nowhere, but if you start with $x_0\ne 0$, $x_n=0$ should never come up.  Please report your ultimate answer, I have computed it so can tell you whether you are right.

Comment: Ok I am getting something really weird now Andre. This is embarassing but $x_n * x_n = x^2_n$ correct? *also I've updated what I have in the post above.

Comment: I seem to have everything cancelling out in the numerator...

Comment: Minus sign error, I make a lot of them too. We have $R-(-R)=2R$. The top should end up as $2x_nR$.

Comment: You are correct! Ahh my mistake. Lol. Is this simplified enough to satisfy as a final answer? Or should I factor out a 2 to get $2 [ \frac{x_n R}{x^2_n + R}]$

Comment: Yes, the end, one cannot do anything useful. There is no further nice cancellation. The *reciprocal* can be made more attractive, but only to a mathematician.

Comment: Andre, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I would up your comments but I dont have enough rep to do that yet.

Comment: You are welcome. If you care to write an answer, please do so. If I know it has been done, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps are mostly in my OP thanks to @André Nicolas .

Computing the final result I got:
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n R}{x^2_n + R},$$ which I further turned into $\frac{2}{1} \left( \frac{x_n R}{x^2_n + R} \right)$.

Comment: Is this what is subtracted from $x_n$ to get the next iteration?